# Filling in gaps around radiator pipes

Tags: radiator, wood-filler, encapsulation

So I've been sleuthing on here for a minute to find an answer to my special quirk here but couldn't find it so now I'm asking.

So I have some annoying holes near my radiators but they connect downward into some red wood floors. And because they're in nice floors my problem is I need a solution that will both fill in the holes but also look nice and match the floor as best they can.

I have seen the nice metallic covers which is doable but I don't think they'll cover my holes completely so I need some sort of solution for the pieces that will inevitably not be covered.

I got some pictures to kind of show what I'm talking about.

But I'm a n00b at home improvement (first home) so be kind lol.[image]

Comment: For the flooring gaps maybe finding some prefinished engineered hardwood samples that are free/cheap at a flooring store that matches to cut up and glue in would work, then using a large radiator flange like you've found

Answer (score 1):

Honestly what works best and looks good the longest for patching things like this in hardwood is your average log cabin **chinking**.   I know that if you get the logjam chinking it will work as I have used it but I am not sure I have seen it in any other size than the 5gallon.

I know this is a simple answer but this is what I have used on 10+ houses for similar things, it hardens, looks cool and doesn't collect dust/dirt like caulk.

Comment: I never knew there was special log cabin gunk!  I thought it was done with natural and woodsy materials like moss, clay and bobcat urine.  :)

Comment: @jay613 - we worked on a house that had a log cabin shed...  we bought a big 5 gallon bucket and used about half of it.   After working with it, decided to try it out on floors... worked great.   I wouldn't use it for cracks or movement things but we have used it with a "missing" piece by trim and to "caulk" around big holes.

Answer (score 0):

Find or buy a board similar to your floor boards.  They look like pine, should be easy to get a piece of 1/2 inch thick pine board.  Find a stain that matches and stain the board before cutting.  Saw pieces that roughly match each hole and glue them in.   Mix clear glue with the sawdust from your cutting and use that to fill the gaps.  Then cover with radiator flanges.